# Cut only a few numbers of given pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have phone numbers on the website that can be in the format:
+48 123456789
48 123456789
123456789

plus, of course, dashes and parentheses, but here I will skip them.

PESEL numbers can also be found on the website - standard 11 characters from 0-9

I only want to select phone numbers, i.e. reject 11-character strings.
I tried something like this and it doesn't work - i.e. I need a space at the end of the phone. How to get around this?

Code below:

```
/((\+?48 ?)?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8})/igm   /*phone number*/
```

```
/((\+?48 ?)?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{8}([^(0-9){11}]))/igm /*here need space after phone number*/
```

I expect to find phone number, without need to give space after last digit.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `/(?:\+?48 ?)?[1-9][0-9]{8}\b/g` should work. Else, use ``/(?:\+?\b48 ?|\b)?[1-9][0-9]{8}(?!\S)/g``.